# jQuery load() function changes the height of an input text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, load

Ok, so I have this html file (sec1_2.html).

```
<body>
<div id="nameContainer">
    <input id="sect1Name">
</div>  
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }

    div#nameContainer {
        background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #000;
        height: 50px;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }

    input#sect1Name {
        width: 330px;   
        margin: 0;
        height: 50px;
        padding: 0;
    }
</style>
```

Is a simple div with an input in it.
As you can see, the height on the div and on the input are the same (50px).
So when you display this page you get the input inside the div at the exact same height.

But, now I have this other html (index.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <div id="section1">
</div>      

<script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#section1").load("sec1_2.html");
</script>
</body>
```

Now, here, I have an empty div where I load the external html (sec1_2.html).
When I do it like this, the (visible) height on the input increases!

I don't know why the input changes, if a let the input without height, both versions display the same height (default), but if I set a defined height, it will show a different height when loaded with jQuery.

Anyone knows why is this happening?

Comment: Use your console to see exactly where the increased height is coming from.

Comment: The console is not showing anything.

Comment: i paste your code in plunker and works fine http://plnkr.co/edit/WDaF1a107ES6mVzhdqEX?p=preview make your own to show your problem

Comment: Your plunker runs the index loading external, and as you can see the difference from running just the external, the input height increases.
http://plnkr.co/edit/VwqGzENOItw1QSwOO0eO?p=preview

Comment: @Danko Can you see the difference between both?

Comment: You're right see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi for some reason your input is been rendered without one default property with the Jquery call, you can add this to your CSS:

```
input#sect1Name {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

This property is assigned for default in the html but not with Jquery.

**http://plnkr.co/edit/6h8U9AQgFaNUb2plPbh6?p=preview**

Comment: Nice!!  
After several tests, I discovered that it was always the same difference on height:  
6px;  

So I thought it could be one specific attribute that I need to specify. It was. So my solution (which I couldn't post yesterday yet) was:  

    border: none;
  
But yours makes more sense. I searched for box-sizing and this explains why it was behaving like that.  

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp
Thanks!